# fail while creating HQL of join in Grails

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, grails, hql

*What we have to achieve*-

> subscribed topics of the user, ordered by latest post entered in the topic.

*What I had done*-I am using following `HQl` query in my `grails` application and its sql is working fine in mysql console -

```
List<Topic> subscriptionList=Topic.executeQuery("select T from Topic T
where id in(select topic from Subscription S join (select distinct(topic) DT 
from Resource order by last_updated desc) TR on  TR.DT=S.topic where user=user)");
```

This is throwing exception/error message-

> unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 101 [select T from
>   com.ig.domain.Topic T where id in(select topic from
>   com.ig.domain.Subscription S join (select distinct(topic) DT from
>   com.ig.domain.Resource order by last_updated desc) TR on 
>   TR.DT=S.topic where user=user)].

following is the error message shown by IDE. [image: error] 
below are model class/entities-

`Resource.groovy`

```
class Resource {

    String description
    Date lastUpdated
    Date dateCreated
    static belongsTo = [user:User,topic:Topic]
    static mapping = {
        user column:'createdBy'
        topic column: 'topic'
        version false
        description nullable:true, blank:true
     }
    static constraints = {}
}
```

`Topic.groovy`

```
    class Topic {

    String name
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    Visibility visibility
    static belongsTo = [createdBy:User]
    static hasMany = [subscription:Subscription,resource:Resource]

    enum Visibility {
        PUBLIC,PRIVATE
    }
    static constraints = {
    }


    static mapping = {
        //user column:'createdBy'
        version false

    }
}
```

`Subscription.groovy`

```
class Subscription {

Date dateCreated

static  belongsTo =[topic:Topic,user:User]

enum Sereousness{
    Sereous,VerySereous,Casual
}

static constraints = {
}
static mapping = {
    user column:'user'
    topic column: 'topic'
    version false
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Subscription and Resource are not associated. As far as i know in hql you can not use join for not associated entities. For this one you need cross joins.
Hibernate docs chapter 16.2 and 16.3 list a few examples 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html

Or you can use the hibernate native query
https://dzone.com/articles/grails-goodness-using